# What is the simplest way to merge two classes in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, merge

I have:

`class Parent {}
class Child1 extends Parent{}
class Child2 extends Parent{}`

I am using all three classes (especially child classes) everywhere in my application. Now the decision was made that child classes should be removed, instead parent class need to hold fields (and methods) from both child classes. How can I easily get needed result?

Only thing came to my mind is to move all child data to Parent class and then `Ctrl+Shift+R` to replace all occurrences of the old classes. Still I wonder, is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: `Refactor` | `Pull Members Up`.

Comment: Thank you for the "pull option". But still, is there a way to replace all occurrences of child classes (also every method to which child classes was passed as a parameters)

Answer (score 12):

Intellij IDEA has a [pull members up](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/pull-members-up.html) refactoring that can help.